# How to find $p$ when $ ({\frac{1}{2}})^p + ({\frac{1}{4}})^p + ({\frac{1}{8}})^p - 1 = 0. $

Tags: problem-solving

Kindly mention solution-techniques along with solution

Comment: And your contribution is ...?

Comment: Hint: $4=2^2$, $8=2^3$, power laws.

Comment: @celtschk So that means that $4 = 8$?

Comment: @timjver: Oops, that was a typo, now fixed, thanks ;-)

Comment: removed comment

Comment: As the OP has (unfortunately) opened a [new version of this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/409925/8348), this version will be closed.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: if $({\frac{1}{2}})^p + ({\frac{1}{4}})^p + ({\frac{1}{8}})^p = 1 $, let $ x=({\frac{1}{2}})^p$,  then $$x+x^2+x^3=1\to \frac{x^4-1}{x-1}=2$$ 
 we can find all Roots of a cubic function by  using the discriminant (see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function)

Comment: How did you conclude that last bit?

Comment: It comes from the formula for a geometric sum.

Comment: @timjver $1+x+\cdots+x^n=\dfrac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$

Comment: Please don't assume they will be in relations like x , x^2 , x^3
Then how to solve ?

Comment: Arnab Dutta:$(\frac{1}{2})^p+(\frac{1}{2})^{p^2}+(\frac{1}{2})^{p^3}=1 $$\to $$\frac{({\frac{1}{2}})^{p^4}-1}{({\frac{1}{2}})^p-1}=2 $ then use discriminant

Comment: Hi everybody:
   If you put values of p(like $\frac{1}{2}$, 2) back in the euation it doesn't satisfy!
  Moreover what - if the equation stands like?:
  $ ({\frac{1}{2}})^p + ({\frac{1}{3}})^p + ({\frac{1}{7}})^p - 1 = 0. $
   (So please dont assume there is relation like $\frac{1}{2},{\frac{1}{2}}^2 ,{\frac{1}{2}}^3 $)